# Does sleeping script will be counted in Entry Processes?

Tags: memory, resources, memory-limit

I'm developing Dating Website with messaging feature. Message Controller script sleeps for a second to check for new Message. But my hosting provider has allowed me 20 Entry Processes. So,

1. Does sleeping script will be counted in Entry Processes?
2. if there are more than 20 users then will the limit be reached and I'll have limit resource error?

If the answer is YES. Then how do I achieve same goal within this limit?

Sample Code:

```
...
while($isNewMessage) {
   $isNewMessage = $model->checkNewMessage();
   sleep($this->sleepTime); //1 second
 }
...
```

Comment: You should rather react to the event when a message got sent by a user instead of constantly polling the message pool.

Comment: @ComFreek can you please explain it a bit? How to do that?

Comment: When using the the 'push' method, you open a long-living connection to each client which is currently online. Assume two users A and B which are currently online. Your script holds a connection to both of them. Now, user A sends a message to user B. The system knows that B is online and that there is a connection to B's client (e.g. a website). Your script therefore sends the incoming message directly through the already opened channel to B.